# IIS + PHP - Configuration File (php.ini) Path - no value

Tags: php, iis

I have a few PHP apps on IIS 10.
I set each app the right PHP version for it, and it works correctly, and the Loaded Configuration File shows the right path for each, however, only the apps using one of the PHP versions have value in the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` when using `phpinfo()`:

[image]

The apps work correctly since the Loaded Configuration File  shows the right path for each app, however I wonder if there's something not set up correctly if one of them has no value in the Path and might cause issues in the future (Maybe it's only saved in cache, and then next time it will try to load it, it won't find it and try to look for it in a wrong path for example?)

Update: For each FastCGI app, I have set the PHPRC environment variable to be the right path to the `php.ini` (In my case, simply the PHP folder for the corresponding version)